# RAM stick intalled, recognized by some tools, but windows still cant use it

Tags: windows, memory, bios

I recently bought a new pc with 2x16 GB Velvet RAM sticks (5600mhz/DDR5).

Both are installed and powered up, according to Cpu-z and HWMonitor, as shown bellow:

[image: cpu-z]

However, Windows is only acessing 16 GB:

[image: pc properties]

I tried to access the memory tweaker tool present in the pc bios. There it shows slot B1 working perfectly with 16 GB avaliable. However, slot A1 shows nothing, as it wasn't even installed.

[image: bios]

I've tried to swap both sticks and restore bios configuration to it's defaults already. The pc doesn't use integrated video as it's processor is an i7-14xxx F.

- MB: Biostar h610mh D5
- CPU: i7-14700F
- GPU: RTX 4070
- OS: Win11 Home SL

Something else I can try?

Comment: Is the RAM single-sided (SS) or double-sided (DS)? According to the manufacturer it only supports a few specific DS ones: https://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=1105#memorysupport

Comment: @ChanganAuto I can't really see clearly as it is covered by a heat sink. However appears to be single sided

Comment: With an heatsink almost 100% chance is DS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto ok, good to know... However, if it wasn't supported, no one would work right?

Comment: No, it works exactly how you're experiencing it. It may work with only one and recognize its full 16GB or only half of each with 2 modules. Weird but it's a situation explicitly mentioned in the link above for TED532G4800C40BK

Comment: Anyway, **contact BioStar**. And while at that ask them about how can they stay in business for so long constantly churning out crap ;)

Comment: Jeez... Gotta have a chat with them. Thanks for the help

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does another OS see and utilize the full 32 GB? For example, if you make a live Ubuntu USB, and boot from it, what does it report RAM as? (I.E., is it a Windows OS issue, or firmware/hardware issue?)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I believe the only limitation for the amount RAM is the OS architecture (32/64 bits for instance). Except, in this specific case where the hardware was the limiting factor